# What is the use of Object.defineProperty if I can also do it much simpler?

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

What is the use of Object.defineProperty ...

```
var myObj = {someNum: 123};
Object.defineProperty(myObj, "anotherNum",
{value: 456, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true});
alert(myObj.someNum + " " + myObj.anotherNum);
```

... if I can also do ...

```
var myObj = {someNum: 321};
myObj.anotherNum = 654;
alert(myObj.someNum + " " + myObj.anotherNum);
```

[jsfiddle over here](http://jsfiddle.net/4HSrr/)

Comment: When you just add the property, you don't get to control the access rights.

Comment: @Pointy: That would be a good answer.

Comment: @wubbewubbewubbe How would you do `Object.defineProperty(myObj, "anotherNum", {value: 456, writable: false});` without `Object.defineProperty`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be fairly clear: the `.defineProperty()` method gives you control over how the property can be accessed.  When you simply add a property to an object, it's always writable, enumerable, and configurable.

The `.defineProperty()` method also lets you set up getter and setter functions.